# Add properties from one array of objects to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following Angular 1.0 controller:

```
function EventListController($timeout, eventService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.events = getEvents();
  vm.calendar buildCalendar();
}
```

The variable vm.events is something like:

```
vm.events = [
  { date: "2016-09-22T12:05:42.03", id: 12 }, 
  { date: "2016-09-25T12:05:42.03", id: 14 }
];
```

The variable calendar is the following:

```
vm.calendar = {
  weeks: [
    { days: [ { date: "2016-09-12T12:05:42.03" }, ... ] }
    { days: [ { date: "2016-09-22T12:05:42.03" }, ... ] }
  ]
}
```

I need to go through all events dates and add the ID property to the calendar date of the same DAY. Calendar weeks has all days of that month. In this case is September 2016.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can iterate both objects

Comment: But how to compare only date and not times?

Comment: compare like `new Date("2016-09-22T12:05:42.03").setHours(0,0,0,0) == new Date("2016-09-22T09:05:42.03").setHours(0,0,0,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate both objects. You can use Date constructor to create Date object and the use [setHours(0,0,0,0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) to set hours, mins.. as zero, then you can only compare date.

```js
var vm = {};
vm.events = [{
  date: "2016-09-22T12:05:42.03",
  id: 12
}, {
  date: "2016-09-25T12:05:42.03",
  id: 14
}];
vm.calendar = {
  weeks: [{
    days: [{
      date: "2016-09-25T09:05:42.03"
    }]
  }]
};

vm.calendar.weeks.forEach(function(w) {
  w.days.forEach(function(d) {
    var e = vm.events.filter(function(e) {
      return new Date(e.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date(d.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    });
    if (e.length) {
      d.id = e[0].id;
    }
    console.log(d)
  })
});

//console.log(vm.calendar.weeks)
```